# FindBy com objeto aninhado - Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Estou com uma dúvida ao criar um findBy usando jpa com atríbuto de um objeto aninhado, as classes são:

```
public class Livro {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String titulo;
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;
```

e

```
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
```

Preciso retornar os livros de um determinado usuário, fornecendo o email dele.

Testei usando esses métodos no repository mas não funcionou:

`List<Livro> findByLivro_Usuario_Email(String email);`

`List<Livro> findByLivroUsuario_Email(String email);`

Vocês tem alguma sugestão do que pode ser?

Comment: acredito que o que você esteja procurando é um findByUsuarioEmail , mas no livros repository

Comment: Você tem razão, fiz a correção aqui e deu certo, ficou assim:
```
@Repository
public interface LivroRepository extends JpaRepository<Livro, Long> {
    List<Livro> findByUsuarioEmail(String email);
}
```
Muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Corrigida utilizando:

```
@Repository
public interface LivroRepository extends JpaRepository<Livro, Long> {
    List<Livro> findByUsuarioEmail(String email);
}
```